# Company Laptop and iTunes/iPhone

Tags: iphone, historical

With their permission, I am selling a company laptop that I used, but I had been using iTunes and syncing my iPhone on that PC. Is it possible for a forensic tech to retrieve any of the browsing history of safari through the stored back ups of my iPhone? And retrieving any emails or messages I have sent out? I had the computer reformatted, but I want to take extra precautions.

I am somewhat wary of leaking any kind of corporate secrets or personal information. Too much money at stake here that can cost me my career. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Reformatting is not sufficient, you need to securely wipe the disk.  Reformatting is like ripping the cover off a book; it's not pretty but all the info is still there.

[DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) is a popular free tool for wiping hard drives.  If the drive is SSD, you [need other tools](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20115106-285/how-to-securely-erase-an-ssd-drive/).

Companies that care will usually not release systems with disks; they'll destroy the disk and whoever buys the laptop/desktop will have to buy a new disk to put in it.  When you look at the overall cost of a system, disk is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 1):

If you're being really paranoid and you want peace of mind, it's probably best to just remove the disk from the laptop and replace it with a new one (as gowenfawr wrote: they're pretty cheap), or with a wiped disk that never contained any sensitive information. Then sell that, and keep your old disk, or destroy it.